# porcess multiple .csv files with code for one, and output as whole

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, multidplyr

I am using R to sum up column "A" in multiple .CSV files, I've prepared code for 1 csv file, is there anyway that i can process all the csv files in one go and output as one?

```
MyFile <- read.csv(tk_choose.files(caption = "Choose CSV files from directory",),header = TRUE)%>% # Select Input CSV Data
transmute(A)%>%
summarise_all(sum,)%>%
write.csv(file = choose.files()) # Output As CSV File)
```

here is the output looks like

```
               A
file1   658839755
```

What i want is

```
            A
file1   658839755
file2   1541654313
file3   4643213843
```

Is it possible to make it happen?

Thanks guys

Comment: Do you have problems opening the files, merging them to one dataframe or to save them?

Comment: Use loops? Something like `write.table(rbindlist(lapply(list.files, function(i){read stuff, do stuff, output})), "final_all_results.txt")`

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-at-once

Comment: Hi guys, I forget to mention, i cant really merging them into one dataframe. They all give me unique output. what i need is process those files in one go and combine the  output into one file.

Comment: This is exactly what loops do, see my example code, loop through files, read them summarise, and finally rowbind them into one datframe which then written out to one file.

Comment: Other option would be to use `for loop`, and `write.table` with option of `append = TRUE`.

Comment: @zx8754 thanks mate, I'm sorry I am a newbie here, need time for finger it out how to loop them...

Comment: @zx8754 Hi mate, i am wondering after i list  those files, how should i define them as df?

Comment: See above related post on how to read multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
csv_path <-"C:/csvfiles/"# set your path to csv files
    data <- readbulk::read_bulk(directory = csv_path,subdirectories = F,extension = ".csv",data = NULL) #read all files into a data frame

    data %>% 
      group_by(File) %>% #group by file name
      summarise(my.sum=sum(A)) %>% # summarise column A using sum
      write.csv(.,"C:/....") # write to csv if you want
```